# Facebook pages "you have created too many pages recently, try later", Facebook error

Tags: facebook-pages

I have 4 pages in a Facebook profiles, 3 of them are 10 years old. I've created a page recently, over 10 days ago. I want to create a new Facebook page and Facebook claims "you have created too many pages recently, try later".

Is there any way to fix this?